# Android LinearLayout with border of transparent pixels

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a row that has a white background with a border of transparent pixels.

```
<LinearLayout android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
```

I'm expecting the background image to be included in the padding. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout_marginTop` etc instead.